# compute EVM for MIMO channel including additive Gaussian white noise

Tags: noise, snr, mimo

Good time. I would like to compute EVM for a Rayleigh channel including additive Gaussian white noise. The accepted EVM for BPSK issued by IEEE is -5dB. Since the variance of white noise depends on the SNR, I am wondering the accepted EVM has been issued for which value of white noise. Could you please help me to resolve the problem. Thanks

Comment: EVM is not commonly used to quantify noise or a channel, but rather imperfections in the transmitter (or sometimes receiver) physical implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess EVM can be calculated for the MIMO channel including noise (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.1187.pdf). My question is how to select the variance of white noise. Because it definitely affect EVM.

Comment: I just read the abstract, but that paper seems to be about phase noise, which is caused by imperfections in the transmitter and is unrelated to the channel fading or AWGN.